# Limit rows when importing data into Excel from SQL Server

Tags: sql, import, excel-2007

When using the Excel Data Connection Wizard (for Excel 2007), is there any simple way to specify how the data is sorted, and also to limit the number of rows returned?

For example, can I easily achieve the equivalent of this SQL statement:

```
Select top 100 * from [TableName] Order by [ColumnName] Desc
```

I have a client who is trying to import data from a table that has more rows than Excel will hold and I am trying to find the simplest way to solve the problem.

Comment: It may have been a while since I used 2007.  But you could do that EXACT thing with 2010.
If you don't have that option, I could recommend building a View inthe database, and linking to that.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Part of the problem is the tools, the other part is the user, and that I am remote from them.  If I could physically do it myself it would have taken me less the 2 minutes.